# Why can I connect AWS-documentDB without using "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" on pymongo

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pymongo, aws-documentdb

AWS says as below.

```
##To encrypt data in transit, download the public key for Amazon DocumentDB named rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem

import pymongo

##Create a MongoDB client, open a connection to Amazon DocumentDB as a replica set and specify the read preference as secondary preferred
client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://<sample-user>:<password>@sample-cluster.node.us-east-1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false')
```

But I can connect aws-documentdb without using "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" on pymongo.

```
import ssl
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(db_host, db_port, username=db_user, password=db_password, ssl=True, ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE)
```

Why can I connect without using "rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem" ??

Answer (score 2):

If you check the Mongo documentation, when you specify `ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE`, you are telling PyMongo to bypass the certificate validation and still allow connection to the server.
https://api.mongodb.com/python/3.3.0/examples/tls.html

However, when you specify the certificate, it would perform server validation using the certificate provided which is a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest .pem file use this link:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/ca_cert_rotation.html